# transform a given time-related column into one that Spotfire can read

Tags: spotfire

I have a time information column formulated as

May 2006

Jun 2006

Aug 2006

...

How to transform this column into a one following Spotfire "Date-time" format.

Comment: As asked, only a Spotfire expert can help. If you tell us what the Spotfire "Date-time" format is, more of us might be able to say something about this.

Comment: Looks like the Spotfire asks the format as  05/2006, 06/2006, 08/2006

Answer (score 1):

If your target column is of String data type, Just change the data type by inserting a transformation and Spotfire will be smart enough to convert it to a Date data type (your dates will start at the beginning of the month. i.e 5/1/2006,6/1/2006,8/1/2006). Then you can apply the formatting you want within column properties. If your column is already a Date or Date Time format, then just change the formatting.

Comment: Hi jleviaguirre, can you elaborate more on this. Assume the input date information is "Jun 2006" of string type. Which kind of transformation you were referring to? Do I need to have to try something similar to "calculated new column" based on expression?

Comment: Just insert a "Change data types"  transformation. Frrom the Spotfire menu: Insert > Transformation > and select [your data table▼], [Chage data types▼] and click [Add..], Then pick the column you want to change the data type, select [Date▼] from the dropdown.  Optionally apply [Formatting...] and make sure the preview looks good. Click [OK] twice and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

So you want the following transformation on your data (this is in python since that's a language I'm comfortable in):

```
result = []
months = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, ..., 'Dec': 12}
for line in data:
    (m, y) = line.split()
    result.append("%02d/%s" % (months[m], y))
```

where data is your list of input rows and result is the output list in the format that Spotfire wants.

If you can find a way to get Spotfire to transform the data as it reads it, perhaps with a 'pivot' step (from looking at the Spotfire website), you might be able to do this entirely within Spotfire. Otherwise, you'll need an external program to do the transformation.

I could produce such a program if you want it, but I would need more detail about where the data is (in a file? database? spreadsheet?) and where the output needs to be put for spotfire to read it (file? database?).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am trying to see how to do it in Spotfire.